# Can we set two foreign key of one primary key in one table in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We have two tables:

**Student table:**  T= Teacher, S= student

```
--------------------------
|  id | name      | Role |
--------------------------
|  1  | Mr.Sharma | T    |
|  2  | Ms.madhu  | T    |
|  3  |  John     | S    |
|  4  |  Smith    | S    |
--------------------------
```

**Assignment table :**

```
--------------------------
|  id | stud_id| tech_id |
--------------------------
|  1  |    3   |   1     |
|  2  |    4   |   2     |
|  3  |    5   |   1     |
|  4  |    6   |   2     |
--------------------------
```

**Expectated result:**

```
------------------------------
|  id | stud_name| tech_name |
------------------------------
|  1  |  John    | Mr.Sharma |
|  2  |  Smith   | Ms.madhu  |
------------------------------
```

How can we get results like this using a single query?
If anyone has a better solution for this please suggest one.

Thank you

Comment: JOIN student table twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN student table twice, the first time to get the student name, the second time to get the teacher name.

```
select a.id, s.name as stud_name, t.name as tech_name 
from assignment a
join student s on a.stud_id = s.id
join student t on a.tech_id = t.id
```